# Redis TTL is always -1 and can't be configured in a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, redis

I can't configure a TTL for the **bucket4j** configuration. It is always -1. Has this soemething to do with the weird key serialization, see screenshot? TTL configuration does work with **other** but not with bucket4j.

```
 @Bean
    fun redisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer(): RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer {
        return RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer { builder ->
            builder
                .withCacheConfiguration(
                    "bucket4j",
                    RedisCacheConfiguration
                        .defaultCacheConfig()
                        .disableCachingNullValues()
                        .entryTtl(Duration.of(100, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
                )
                .withCacheConfiguration(
                    "other",
                    RedisCacheConfiguration
                        .defaultCacheConfig()
                        .disableCachingNullValues()
                        .entryTtl(Duration.of(100, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
                )
        }
    }
```

application.properties:

```
spring.redis.database=0
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=16379
spring.redis.password=mypass
spring.redis.timeout=60000

spring.cache.cache-names=other,bucket4j
```

[image: Redis]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the config: `spring.cache.redis.time-to-live`

Comment: Unfortunately this setting has no affect on the TTL.